# JavaFX: Как добавить ImageIcon к каждому элементу списка?

Tags: java, javafx, grid-layout

У меня есть 2 класса(код ниже), также есть 52 картинки, я хочу создать сетку из 52 картинок и присвоить каждую картинку соответствующему элемент списка. Подскажите, как это сделать

Card.java:

```
package com.company.chasie;

/**
 * Created by chasie on 30.09.16.
 */
public class Card {
private String rank;
private String suit;

private Card() {
}

public Card(String rank, String suit) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.rank + " of " + this.suit;
}
}
```

Desk.java:

```
package com.company.chasie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by chasie on 30.09.16.
 */
public class Desk {
private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

public Desk() {
    String[] rank = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
    String[] suit = {"Club", "Spade", "Diamond", "Heart"};
    for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
            this.cards.add(new Card(rank[i], suit[j]));
        }
    }
}

public Object GetCard(int value) {
    Card card = cards.get(value);
    return card;
}

public Object SetCard(int index, Card card) {
    return cards.set(index, card);
}

public void Shuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(this.cards);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать класс [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html). Далее вы должы создать этот ImageView ( посредством класса [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) или [пути до картинки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#ImageView-java.lang.String-)).

Далее, чтобы создать сетку, необходимо использовать [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).

Вот простой пример, как добавить все картинки ( из учета, что переопределенный метод в классе `Card` - путь до картинки).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestDesk extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        Desk desk = new Desk();
        int currentRow = 0;
        int currentColumn = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < desk.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i % 4 == 0)
            {
                RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
                rowConstraints.setPrefHeight(20); // выставляем предпочитаемую высоту. Если необходимо, другие параметры тоже выставляем.
                grid.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);
                currentRow++;
                currentColumn = 0;
            }

            grid.add(new ImageView(desk.GetCard(i).toString()), currentColumn++, currentRow);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Данный пример нарисует сетку размером в 4 колонки и 13 строк.

**P.S.** добавил в класс `Desk` метод `size()`, который возвращает размер коллекции `cards`.

**P.S.S.** Так же, вместо `ImageView` можно использовать любой другой [Labeled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html) и использовать метод [setGraphic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-), куда передать `ImageView`.